# How to pass build parameters/env variable to powershell pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkinsfile that defines a pipeline. In there, I declared a step which invokes the powerhell pipeline plugin and I am trying to use the jenkins environment variables as well as a build parameter with no success. See my step definition below:

```
stage('publish') {
      steps {
            powershell returnStatus: true, script: '$(env:WORKSPACE)\\ci\\scripts\\publish-$(BRANCH).ps1'
      }
    }
```

Any help/insight will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your pipeline:

1. Single quotes will not extend variables inside the string
2. To access variables you user ${var} and not $(var)
3. Not wrong, but you do not need to use env.WORKSPACE, just WORKSPACE is sufficient

Please give it a try, you can add the echo before your powershell command so you can see what you are trying to execute.

```
stage('publish') {
  steps {
        echo "${WORKSPACE}\\ci\\scripts\\publish-${BRANCH}.ps1"
        powershell returnStatus: true, script: ${WORKSPACE}\\ci\\scripts\\publish-${BRANCH}.ps1"
  }
}
```